# Why am I getting captchas?

Tags: support, captcha

Recently, every time I try to post a question, I'm faced with a captcha asking if I am a robot or human. Could this be because I take a lot of time when writing questions, or perhaps because I am using Stack Exchange from my phone?

Comment: Shouldn't happen, maybe it's related to your IP e.g. shared with suspicious accounts, or being changed rapidly which is also suspicious for the anti-spam mechanism.

Comment: Is there a solution ?

Comment: Sorry, not a dev, just shared my own thoughts about it.